# How can i create foreign_key with two tables in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i am new in rails 4 . i have two tables likes this :

```
  create_table "reservoirs", primary_key: "idEmbalse", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string   "nombre"
    t.integer  "idJunta"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "joints", primary_key: "idJunta", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string   "nombre"
    t.string   "color"
    t.integer  "numero"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["nombre", "color", "numero"], name: "index_joints_on_nombre_and_color_and_numero", unique: true, using: :btree
  end
```

I tried create a relathionship idJunta 
between joints and reservoirs but nothing of documentation work . how can i relation idJunta? . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use has_many and belongs_to??

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/association_basics.html

4.1.2.5 :foreign_key

By convention, Rails assumes that the column used to hold the foreign key on this model is the name of the association with the suffix _id added. The :foreign_key option lets you set the name of the foreign key directly:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, class_name: "Patron",
                        foreign_key: "patron_id"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to assign the primary key in the model rather than in the migration because it's better readable for yourself and for other people.

```
  create_table "reservoirs", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string   "nombre"
    t.integer  "idJunta"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "joints", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string   "nombre"
    t.string   "color"
    t.integer  "numero"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["nombre", "color", "numero"], name: "index_joints_on_nombre_and_color_and_numero", unique: true, using: :btree
  end
```

Run rake db:migrate (or rails db:migrate on rails 5>)

**Then in your Reservoir model do this:**

```
class Reservoir < MailForm::Base
  self.primary_key = "person_id"
end
```

**And in your Joint model:**

```
class Joint < MailForm::Base
  self.primary_key = "idJunta"
end
```

Comment: i want create a reference between  ids ... this not work

Comment: You can change t.integer  "idJunta" to t.references "idJunta"